# Please check my error this series expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have beeen able to derive the series for $e^{-x^2}$ and want to find the series representation for $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$:

$$e^{-x^2}=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^8}{4!}+ \cdots$$
$$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2\cdot2!}-\frac{x^6}{2\cdot3!}+\frac{x^8}{2\cdot4!}+\cdots$$

The coefficient seems wrong, for example the third term is $\dfrac{x^4}{4}$, while Wolfram gives me the coefficient as $\dfrac{x^4}{8}$.

Comment: Why can't you use $e^x$ series directly? Anyways, $e^{-x^2/2} = e^{-(x/\sqrt{2})^2}$. so you have to replace $x$ by $x/\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\textbf{wrong: } & & & e^{-x^2/2}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2\cdot2!}-\frac{x^6}{2\cdot3!}+\frac{x^8}{2\cdot4!}+\cdots \\[10pt]
\textbf{right: } & & & e^{-x^2/2}=1-\frac{x^2}{2^1\cdot1!}+\frac{x^4}{2^2\cdot2!}-\frac{x^6}{2^3\cdot3!}+\frac{x^8}{2^4\cdot4!}+\cdots
\end{align}
This is because $\left( \dfrac {x^2} 2 \right)^4 = \dfrac{x^8}{2^4}, $ etc.

Comment: But the second term is gonna be $(\dfrac{x^2}{2})^2=\dfrac{x^4}{4}$; which is wrong because it should be $\dfrac{x^2}{2}$; according to Wolfram, no?

Answer (score 1):

The general term for
$e^x$ is
$\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$.

For $e^{-x^2/2}$,
this becomes
$\dfrac{(-x^2/2)^n}{n!}
=\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}
$.